# Partitions 3 on /dev/sda have been written, but we have been unable to inform the kernel of the change

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, gparted, error-handling

So i recently tried to install pheonix os along side Windows 10 and it basically destroyed my partitions for good. So i tried to install Ubuntu and just wipe my drive completely using gparted. I then came upon this error when trying to delete the drives. So i tried to use the installer to just erase the disk and install Ubuntu and it gave me this error again. I then chose the something else option to see if i could delete them from there, yet everything was unchangeable and it wouldn't let me do anything. Help?
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xu4Rv.jpg)

Comment: You've not provided any product/release details; my guess is it's Ubuntu Desktop, but I can't see which release from details you've provided, nor which ISO/installer you opted to use (*if it's a release with choice as that detail wasn't provided*)

Comment: This message indicates the partitions you are trying to delete are currently in use.  You can try deleting them, writing the results, and then rebooting to install media.